# how to move a page from one drop down menu to another drop down menu

Tags: wp-query, functions

I have a page that is posted under one heading but I want to move the whole page to another drop down... for example

from 'FOR SALE' drop down

to 'RESULTS' drop down

Answer (score 0):

If it's defined in a custom menu in your theme, then Find the menu settings and drag it from where it is to where you want it to be, or remove from the one menu add to the other.
https://www.wpupgrader.com/wordpress/change-menu-navigation-settings/
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide#Customizing_Menu_Items.

If it's a custom menu, just the default page hierarchy then edit the page and change the page parent https://www.jezweb.info/change-parent-page/